# C++ if statement not registering "-f" as a possible value

Tags: c++

Hey so recently I tried getting a C++ program of mine to take in a parameter "-f" (it helps create a file of data that the user can enter), and so I tried the typical if statement:

```
if (argv[1] == "-f") { cout << "Please input a file name:" << endl;}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The code is registering that "-f" is an argument to add to argc, it just doesn't want to check that it's properly "-f". I even tried atoi to change "f" to 102 and check it via an integer, but it just doesn't seem to be working. Thank you for your time!

Comment: `atoi` doesn't convert `"f"` to `102`. `atoi("f")` is `0` because it's not a number.

Comment: I'm not doing that, I'm checking if atoi(argv[1]) is equal to 102.

Comment: Yes, and if `argv[1]` is `"-f"`, then that amounts to `atoi("-f")`, which is `0` because `-f` is not a number.

Answer (score 7):

`argv[1] == "-f"` is a pointer comparison. It will never be true because a command line argument will never have the same address as a string literal in your program.

Try `if (strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0)` instead.

Comment: Or `if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-f")`

Answer (score 0):

Both `argv[something]` and `-f` are *C-style* strings which decay (in most cases) to a pointer to the first character of that string.

Hence a simple comparison, unlike the `std::string` type, will not work since it will be comparing two distinct pointers. If you want to compare C-style strings, `strcmp` and its brethren are the way to go.

Otherwise you can turn both those values into *actual* C++ strings and use the equality operator to compare them.

I'd opt for the former:

```
if (strcmp (argv[1], "-f") == 0) {
    argOneIsMinusF();
}
```